# Why do I die when I run "/kill @e [type=!player]"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I put

```
/kill @e [type=!player]
```

in a command block and power it, I die, even though players should be excluded. I need this command to be able to reset my mini-game map, but I don't know how to do it! Am I doing it wrong?

I've found other websites that say its just like that, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are there any other command blocks hooked up with a `/kill` command that could be causing trouble?

Comment: @RavenM nope. Its the only one. I literally just have a lever attached to some redstone and the command block .-.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found your problem.

Your command has a space between the `@e` and the type selector. Simply remove this space, and don't forget to capitalized the P.

Correct command: `/kill @e[type=!Player]`

Comment: If this helped, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Also to note: The first letter, `p`, needs to be capitalized to work.

Comment: Sorry, missed that too. Edited.

Comment: Also @AngusAtkinson , is there able to be more than one /kill command block near it with the same redstone current? I'm trying that and its not working .-.

Comment: @xXPikminXx It should work. Is the redstone actually powering the block? Does the command have a Capital P and not space? If your not sure about the power, replace the command block with a redstone lamp to check.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson Its not. It worked perfectly fine with other commands and a redstone lamp, but I guess its just the way the /kill command works .-.

Comment: @xXPikminXx Why do you have several kill commands? To kill different things?

Comment: no so I can keep from killing certain things like zombies and players. @AngusAtkinson

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23032/discussion-between-angus-atkinson-and-xxpikminxx).